# Split the lists dynamically

Tags: r

I have a list

```
query= { "id":"2317",   "product":"112",  "tag":"A,B,C"}
```

I want the output like this -

```
query1= { "id":"2317",   "product":"112",  "tag":"A"}
query2= { "id":"2317",   "product":"112",  "tag":"B"}
query3= { "id":"2317",   "product":"112",  "tag":"C"}
```

p.s: the tag contains any number of items ranging from 1 to n items. So if the tag has "n" items, then we need to get "n" number of queries.

Can someone help me how can we do it in R? maybe with the help of loops or whatever works.

Thank you in advance.>!

Note: in R the query would be stored as a character. So I am using query=fromJSON(query), then it would be stored as a list.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example.  Is it a `list` or  a string `'{...}'`

Comment: Hi, it is a list, I edited the question, you can refer the last lines in the question. I am using library(jsonlite) to convert it to list

Comment: Please update with the `dput` of the 'query'

Comment: @akrun dput is:  `list(id = "2317", product = "112", tag = "A,B,C")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to first convert it to a dataframe, split the tag column, and convert it back to a JSON:

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(fromJSON('{ "id":"2317",   "product":"112",  "tag":"A,B,C"}'))
s <- strsplit(df$tag, split = ",")
n <- length(unlist(s))
df <- data.frame(id = rep(df$id, n), product = rep(df$product, n), tag = unlist(s))
toJSON(df)
```

This will give you:

```
[{"id":"2317","product":"112","tag":"A"},{"id":"2317","product":"112","tag":"B"},{"id":"2317","product":"112","tag":"C"}]
```

---

You can easily write this to a file using `jsonlite::write_json(df, path = 'file_name.json')`

Comment: @Avinash No problem glad I could help!, please mark my answer as accepted to let other users now your question is answered

Comment: Yes, codeNoob, I am incorporating it my project. once it runs successfully, I will do that..!

Comment: @Avinash Yeah no problem, let me know if you have any problems with that